# How can I set PortletSession in JSP page in Liferay MVC?

Tags: jsp, content-management-system, liferay-6

In a Liferay MVC project how can I set `portletSession` in JSP page and retrieve `portletSession` in a custom action class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From JSP you don't need to do anything because is one of the objects provided:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<portlet:defineObjects />
<%
    portletSession.getAttribute(...);
%>
```

From a class is not a big deal neither, it's available in your render or action methods:

```java
PortletSession portletSession = actionRequest.getPortletSession(); // action method
PortletSession portletSession = renderRequest.getPortletSession(); // render method
```